# Detect and extract face from an image

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection, feature-detection, feature-extraction

I have been trying to do the following - 
When a user uploads an Image in my web app, I'd like to detect his/her face in it and extract face (from forehead to chin and cheek to cheek) from it.

- I tried OpenCV/C++ face detection using Haar Cascade but problem with it is that it gives a probability of where the face would be because of which either background of image comes inside the ROI or even the complete face doesn't come in the ROI.
  I also want to detect eye inside the face and while using the above technique, the eye detection isn't that accurate.
- I've read up on a new technique called [Active Appearance Model (AAM](https://code.google.com/p/asmlib-opencv/)). The [blogs](http://codecapsule.com/2010/08/12/active-appearance-models-in-c-plus-plus/) where I read up about this show that this is exactly what I want but I am lost on how to implement this.

My queries are -

1. Is using AAM a good idea for face detection and face feature detection.
2. Are there any other techniques for doing the same.

Any help on any of these is much appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you noticed OpenCV's implementation of face detection is not state-of-the-art. It is a very good and robust implementation but you can do better.

Recently, Zhu and Ramanan (CVPR 2012) had intoduced [Face detection, pose estimation and landmark localization in the wild](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~xzhu/face/) which is considered to be one of the leading algorithms for face detection in recent years.
Their algorithm is capable of detecting faces both frontal and profile views AND identifying keypoints on the detected face such as eyes nose and mouth.

The authors were kind enough to publish their code along with learned models, it is a Matlab implementation but the main computations are done in C++, so it should not be too difficult to make a standalone C++ implementation of thier method.

Comment: @ShivangDoshi I guess it will take you a while to explore. How familiar are you with computer vision algorithms/methods?

Comment: can you provide me with any links that you think can help me increase my familiarity.

Comment: @ShivangDoshi There is quite a bit to read, depending on your current knowledge. This algorithm is based on "parts model" paradigm (see ref [14] TPAMI 2009 in Zhu and Ramanan's paper). I guess you can treat their code as a "black box" and just port it to C++. In that case you'll need some basic Matlab experience.

Comment: sure..btw are you also familiar with AAM? can you share your views about it ?

Comment: @ShivangDoshi I'm afraid I do not have enough experience with AAM. I am more familiar with Zhu&Ramanan's method.

Comment: no problem..really appreciate your help..i m still onto Zhu&Ramanan

Comment: buddy your answer was really helpful..i've started working on it but i need some help so can we connect somewhr maybe over mail ?

Comment: @ShivangDoshi if you have specific questions you can post them here at SO.

Comment: You can also use skin detection to improve the results along with the above algo.

Comment: @ArminMustafa indeed. but can you be more specific? Can you point to a good reference/source?